# How to make HTML content occupy all the available height?

Tags: html, css

Please, consider the following jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/hwCuB/ (you can find the code after the body of the question).

It represents a trivial example of the classic header, content, footer HTML layout. Notice that:

1. The content never overlaps with the footer. Resizing the window will finally create a vertical scrollbar rather than move the content over the footer.
2. There are no redundant scrollbars.
3. No absolute heights, except of the footer, which may be assumed to be no higher than 2em.
4. The content height is less than the available height between the header and the footer.

I would like to keep the first three properties, but change the last one, so that the content height is the full height between the header and the footer. And I would like to do so without resorting to javascript.

How can I do so, if at all?

**EDIT**

The given html and css are just an example. You are free to change them as long as the final result satisfies the conditions of my question.

**EDIT2**

Apparently, I am not very clear on what I want to achieve with the content. Here is what I have now:
[image]

Notice how the content does not extend the full height available to it between the header and the footer.

What I am after is this:
[image]

(edited in mspaint, I do not know to do it really)

**EDIT3**

Added an except clause to the 3rd condition:

> except of the footer, which may be assumed to be no higher than 2em.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.7.3/build/cssreset/reset-min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="header">
     Header goes here.
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="innerWrapper">
      Content goes here.
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <div class="status">
       Footer goes here.
    <div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>​
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    position: relative; /* needed for footer positioning*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.content {
    padding: 0em 0em 2em; /* bottom padding for footer */
    background-color: #bbb;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0; /* stick to bottom */
}

.status, .header {
    background-color: #999;
    border: solid 1px #000000;
}
```

​

Comment: Where's your <body> tag? <head> is not closed.

Comment: I can only say "oops" in my justification.

Answer (score 1):

There might be couple ways to do this, but the only ways i can think of at the moment all involve setting/knowing the height of your header and footer.

Here is one using `display:table` http://jsfiddle.net/fLnkf/

There may be other solutions depending on if your requirements allow you to change your html or use CSS3.

hope this helps!

Comment: By all means, change the HTML and the CSS. Just make sure the conditions of the question are satisfied.

Comment: There is a redundant vertical scrollbar - breaks condition 2.

Comment: fun question :) Here are two options [http://jsfiddle.net/FeeaD/](http://jsfiddle.net/FeeaD/). Using some bleeding edge CSS3 and falling back on some window resizing javascript.

Comment: It was not an update - the no javascript statement is there from the beginning. But still, if there are no other suggestions...

Comment: Please, see EDIT2. I think you got wrong what I want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry and thanks for the clarification.  I don't know of any pure css way (cross browser) to do what you want to do without setting fixed heigts on header/footer.  I've also tried [this old-school approach](http://jsfiddle.net/5KwTD/). Is it close to what you mean?

Comment: +1 for the persistance :-). I have slightly modified the third condition - the footer height is known to be no higher than 2em. What you did with tables is very close, except that the footer height is not constant, notice how it changes when you max the frame height. But other than that - yes. Is that it - back to tables? What's so good in the new school if things that are simple with the old one are impossible in the new school?

Comment: life is circular... :) my last solution led me [to this](http://jsfiddle.net/RMNsQ/), without tables.  It uses `display:table` and `display:table-row`.  It's css to mimic table behavior :) Gonna call it a day with this one.  Good learning exercises though. Thanks for the +1.